# Execute DOS command within console application VB

Tags: vb.net, command-line, cmd

I need to be able to execute a DOS command, such as 'ipconfig', using a command line application in Visual Basic. I can simply use start.process("CMD", "ipconfig"), but that opens a new instance of CMD. I want to be able to run a command like I would with CMD, using a console application, without opening another CMD window. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean on an already open CMD instance?

Comment: Yes :) I don't want more windows popping up, I just want it run in the original CMD application form.

Comment: I know what's the next question!  "How can I read the results"

Comment: You can launch a command window from your console app but keep it invisible to the user... is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to run the `ipconfig` command in hidden console window and redirect the output to local variable. From here you can manipulate it as needed:

```
Dim cmdProcess As New Process
With cmdProcess
    .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C ipconfig")
    With .StartInfo
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    End With
    .Start()
    .WaitForExit()
End With

' Read output to a string variable.
Dim ipconfigOutput As String = cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: It's not at all a bad idea, but I think he wants to get the output in his own command line application. At least this is what I have understood from the title.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - If so, just write the contents of `ipconfigOutput` to the console.

Comment: Matteo NNZ, yes, I would like to do what you said. Jason, I tried what you suggested and got this error: StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.

Comment: @SamStenner - I updated the answer. I forgot to add the `.RedirectStandardOutput = True` under the `.StartInfo`.

Comment: Also, one other thing - sometimes I want everything to be printed to the console, but sometimes I want it to be run silently, so it's still run, just not all displayed in the console. Is that possible?

Comment: @SamStenner - The snippet above does not output to the console, it keeps the output in a local variable. You can apply whatever logic you need to determine if you actually want to write it to console of our application's output.

Comment: Why not just run ipconfig.exe directly?  Why is it necessary to run another instance of cmd.exe?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - As I understand it, the OP wants to use its output in his program.

Comment: Redirecting output still works.  The code you posted seems to work by just directly staring ipconfig.exe instead of cmd.exe.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - It executes `ipconfig` in a hidden window (per the question) using a `cmd` process so that the output can be examined/manipulated within the program logic before it is output.

Comment: I agree, but what I meant was that I took the code you posted and changed only the one line to:  `.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("ipconfig.exe")`  It works as expected.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I can see how that would work because `ipconfig` has almost an instant return. However, I have traditionally used the "verbose form" above for commands which may take more time to run. I have the snippet above in a common library so I haven't reviewed it in a while as it has always "just worked" for me.